# Decision Making Based On User Input

Tags: c, cs50

I'm very new to coding and currently at the beginning of CS50 course on edx (therefore I'm learning C at the moment). I am trying to practice by writing programs with what I have learned so far (admittedly, not much) and I think I overextended a bit.

I am trying to write an income tax calculator. I have already wrote a simple one that uses basic if_else statements depending on the amount entered at the start of the program. Now I am trying a slightly more complicated one. Basically, at the start of program the user is prompted whether the type of the income is salary or private income. Depending on the answer, it chooses a direction and uses the related if_else statements for income tax brackets. I have gotten it to work, but not like I originally intended to.

Currently, if the income type is salary, the user types in S. Otherwise, the user types P and based on this input the program uses correct brackets. As I said, brackets are different depending on the type of the income.

What I am wondering is, how can I code my program to use strings (such as "Salary" and "Private") instead of using chars ('S' and 'P')? I have literally spent hours on this but with my current knowledge I'm not sure if I can find a solution on my own.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>


int main(void)
{
    char c = get_char("Income Type(S/P): ");
    int x = get_int("Your Income: ");
    int y;


    if (c == 'S')

    {

        if (x <= 14800)
            {
            y = x * 0.15;
            printf("Your Income Tax: %i\n", y);
            }

            else if ( x > 14800 && x <= 34000)
            {
            y = (14800 * 0.15) + (x - 14800) * 0.20;
            printf("Your Income Tax: %i\n", y);
            }

            else if ( x > 34000 && x <= 120000)
            {
                y = (14800 * 0.15) + ((34000 - 14800) * 0.20) + (x - 34000) * 0.27;
                printf("Your Income Tax: %i\n", y);
            }

            else
            {
                y = (14800 * 0.15) + ( (34000 - 14800) * 0.20) + ((120000 - 34000) * 0.27) + (x - 120000) * 0.35;
                printf("Your Income Tax: %i\n", y);
            }

    }

    else if (c == 'P')

    {

    if (x <= 14800)
    {
    y = x * 0.15;
    printf("Your Income Tax: %i\n", y);
    }

    else if ( x > 14800 && x <= 34000)
    {
    y = (14800 * 0.15) + (x - 14800) * 0.20;
    printf("Your Income Tax: %i\n", y);
    }

    else if ( x > 34000 && x <= 80000)
    {
        y = (14800 * 0.15) + ( (34000 - 14800) * 0.20) + (x - 34000) * 0.27;
        printf("Your Income Tax: %i\n", y);
    }

    else
    {
        y = (14800 * 0.15) + ( (34000 - 14800) * 0.20) + ((80000 - 34000) * 0.27) + (x - 80000) * 0.35;
        printf("Your Income Tax: %i\n", y);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: As far as I remember, strings come a little later during CS50. So just stick to it.

Comment: You'd have to use a different input function — probably the `get_string()` function provided by the CS50 library — and then use `strcmp()` to compare what the user provided with what you expected.  You might have to worry about niceties such as "is `salary` the same as `Salary`"; that requires a different string comparison function from `strcmp()` (though which depends on the platform you're working on; the answer differs between Windows and Unix-like platforms).  And you might have to worry about leading and trailing white space (tabs, blanks) too.

Comment: Thank you both for your inputs. I have actually found out about `strcmp()` and tried to employ it in a way that if the result was 0, the first path would be taken. else, second set of if_else statements and brackets would be used. But for some reason I could never got it to work, it always used the second path. If you have time to check out, I can also post the version I'm talking about.